# Most optimal way of importing external libraries in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, import

The example is I have an external library such as Materialize.js, the components I need to render depend on it, what is the best way to include this library? The documentation of ReactJS refers to "Code Splitting" which I have done with my own JavaScript but cannot do with an external minimized script. What approach yields the highest performance?

I have tried the following

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();      
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

scriptLoaded = async () => {
   this.setState({materializeJsLoaded: true});
}
```

I have also then also tried including it in the index.html page at the bottom of the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Code split at the build level not in component did mount. find a lib for webpack (or maybe webpack does it for you). The look into conditional imports. these are async imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that discusses creating a custom css build and importing javascript on a per-component basis:

https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9

[image]